# Dismiss Modalview after imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, dismiss, modal-view

I have a ViewController (VC1) that opens another ViewController (VC2) modally that is embedded in a NavigationController (NavC1). VC2 is used as a source selection view for the user to select different sources, such as the built-in photo library. When the user selects the photo library in VC2 I am opening Apple's imagePicker.

`VC1 --(modal)--> NavC1 ----> VC2`

In the imagePickerdidFinish I would like to close the before modally presented VC2.
Actually this method looks as follows.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    ...

    NSError* error;
    if([UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete error:&error] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Saving image to file failed with error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }

    picker.delegate = nil;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    ...
}
```

What I have tried so far:

- I have tried to dismiss it using the parent navigation controller
- I have stored a reference to VC2 in `prepareForSegue:` of VC1 and
  passed a delegate back to VC1 from VC2 when the imagePicker did
  finish. In this method I have tried to simply dimiss the modal view
  manually (`[self.myModalView
  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`)

Does anyone have a suggestion for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming to VC2 by `[self.navigationController PushViewController:VC2Object animated:YES];` then you need to pop it i.e `[self.navigationController popViewController];`

If you are coming to VC2 by `[self.navigationController presentedViewController];` then you need to `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Therefore, check how you are loading VC2 viewController in memory.

Comment: Mh... I am not doing it manually. I have set up a Segue from VC1 to VC2 and set the style to `Modal`. But anyway, `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` does not work because this closes the imagePicker and not the tableView in which I have opened the picker.